# I have working Javascript code that that converts any number entered into its text equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, 4 is converted to "Four" and 33333 is converted to "Thirty three thousands three hundred and thirty three". I am thinking of using JQUERY instead of plain JAVASCRIPT.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    function NumberToTextConverter()
    {
        this.TEN = 10;
        this.HUNDRED = 100;
        this.THOUSAND = 1000;
        this.MILLION = 1000000;
        this.BILLION = 1000000000;
        this.wordList = new Array("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen");
        this.wordList2 = [];
        this.initializeTwentys(); // this would populate the twentys

    }

    NumberToTextConverter.Convert = function(number)
    {
        var currentConverter = new NumberToTextConverter();
        return currentConverter.Convert(number);
    };

    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.Convert = function(number)
    {
        var quotient = Math.floor(number / this.BILLION);
        var remainder = number % this.BILLION;
        var word = "";
        var realValue = "";
        var converter = this;
        if (number < this.BILLION)
        {
            return converter.ConvertToMillions(number);
        }
        else
        {
            var quotientValue = quotient.toString();
            if (quotientValue.length == 3)
            {
                realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertHundreds(quotient) + " billions ";
            }
            else if (quotientValue.length == 2)
            {
                realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertToDoubleDigit(quotient) + " billions ";
            }
            else
            {
                realValue = realValue + this.wordList[quotient] + " billions ";
            }
            realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertToMillions(remainder);
        }
        return realValue;
    };
    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.ConvertToMillions = function(number)
    {
        var quotient = Math.floor(number / this.MILLION);
        var remainder = number % this.MILLION;
        var word = "";
        var realValue = "";
        var converter = this;
        if (number < this.MILLION)
        {
            return converter.ConverToThousands(number);
        }
        else
        {
            var quotientValue = quotient.toString();
            if (quotientValue.length == 3)
            {
                realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertHundreds(quotient) + " millions ";
            }
            else if (quotientValue.length == 2)
            {
                realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertToDoubleDigit(quotient) + " millions ";
            }
            else
            {
                realValue = realValue + this.wordList[quotient] + " millions ";
            }
            realValue = realValue + converter.ConverToThousands(remainder);
        }
        return realValue;
    };
    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.ConverToThousands = function(number)
    {
        var quotient = Math.floor(number / this.THOUSAND);
        var remainder = number % this.THOUSAND;
        var word = "";
        var realValue = "";
        var converter = this;
        if (number < this.THOUSAND)
        {
            return converter.ConvertHundreds(number);
        }
        else
        {
            var quotientValue = quotient.toString();
            if (quotientValue.length == 3)
            {
                realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertHundreds(quotient) + " thousands ";
            }
            else if (quotientValue.length == 2)
            {
                realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertToDoubleDigit(quotient) + " thousands ";
            }
            else
            {
                realValue = realValue + this.wordList[quotient] + " thousands ";
            }
            realValue = realValue + converter.ConvertHundreds(remainder);
        }
        return realValue;
    };

    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.ConvertHundreds = function(number)
    {
        var quotient = Math.floor(number / this.HUNDRED);
        var remainder = number % this.HUNDRED;
        var word = "";
        var converter = this;
        if (number >= 100)
        {
            return this.wordList[quotient] + " hundred " + converter.ConvertToDoubleDigit(remainder);
        }
        else
        {
         return   converter.ConvertToDoubleDigit(remainder);
        }
    };
    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.initializeTwentys = function()
    {
        this.wordList2[0] = "";
        this.wordList2[1] = "TEN";
        this.wordList2[2] = "TWENTY";
        this.wordList2[3] = "THIRTY";
        this.wordList2[4] = "FOURTY";
        this.wordList2[5] = "FIFTY";
        this.wordList2[6] = "Sixty";
        this.wordList2[7] = "Seventy";
        this.wordList2[8] = "Eighty";
        this.wordList2[9] = "Ninety";
    };
    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.ConvertSingleDigit = function(number)
    {
        return this.wordList[number];
    };
    NumberToTextConverter.prototype.ConvertToDoubleDigit = function(number)
    {
        var quotient = Math.floor(number / this.TEN);
        var remainder = number % this.TEN;
        var word = "";
        if (number > 19)
        {
            switch (quotient)
            {
                case 2: word = this.wordList2[2]; break;
                case 3: word = this.wordList2[3]; break;
                case 4: word = this.wordList2[4]; break;
                case 5: word = this.wordList2[5]; break;
                case 6: word = this.wordList2[6]; break;
                case 7: word = this.wordList2[7]; break;
                case 8: word = this.wordList2[8]; break;
                case 9: word = this.wordList2[9]; break;
            }
            return word + " " + this.wordList[remainder];
        }
        else
        {
            return this.wordList[number];
        }
    };

    function PleaseConvert()
    {

        var value = document.getElementById("txtNumberInput").value;
        var checkValue = NumberToTextConverter.Convert(parseInt(value));

        var currentSpanTag = document.getElementById("spanText");
        currentSpanTag.style.backgroundColor = '#aadd88';
        currentSpanTag.style.border = 'dotted 1px #333377';
        currentSpanTag.innerHTML = checkValue;
    }
```

Your opinions and ideas are appreciated!! My Question is whether it would be  good idea to spend time by implementing this logic using JQUERY? Here is the working code :
http://www.coolaspdotnetcode.com/Web/JavaScriptInfoAndCode.aspx

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: So, you want SO to refactor this as jQuery script. How thoughtful ;P

Comment: From the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq : "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: @Daniel - his question is implicit. Make the above into jQuery. Any takers?

Comment: @Daniel- I assume he wants us to give him the jquery equivalent

Comment: @karim79- you can have it..  :)

Comment: @TStamper - I've done more than my fair share for the day, but if you answer, I'll be forced to compete :D

Comment: @People who responded to me: Shiva edited his question after I made my initial comment.  That paragraph after the code was not there when I posted my comment.  :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "convert to jQuery code"? jQuery has really pretty much nothing to do with the code you posted. It is not a different language, it has no magic that will make the Javascript any different. jQuery is a library intended to make it easy to manipulate DOM elements and perform common Javascript tasks cross-browser. It *is* Javascript, and there's nowhere really where it would fit to have a function such as this one.

If what you really mean is "make a plugin out of this", then it's a 5 liner:

```
$.fn.humanizeNumber = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).html(CALLTHEFUNCTION($(this).html()));
    }
});
```

Where `CALLTHEFUNCTION` is whatever is the main function of the code you posted above (I don't really care to go through it and find what it is). That plugin would then let you do this:

```
$('#myelement').humanizeNumber();
```

To convert the value in `#myelement` from "123" to whatever your function returns.

Comment: @Paolo - +1, I don't think he means to make it a plugin, but a brilliant suggestion nontheless - plus a brilliant rant. You took it seriously, where others (including myself) couldn't. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

If it's already done this way and it's working I don't see why spending time implementing this in jQuery.

Unless if you want to learn/practice jQuery.

Comment: yes it is working, but I am just wondering how JQUERY might facilitate by making it more robust or better refactored code , You know what I mean?

Comment: I didn't review your code so I can't say how robust it is, but jQuery is a JavaScript library. You can make robust Javascript code. Next javascript you write you can use jquery. Imagine if you change all your javascript every time a new lib is released.

Comment: +1 for this line "Imagine if you change all your javascript every time a new lib is released."

Comment: the first post I read from joel spolsky and when I discovered joelonsoftware http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html I know it is talking about a bigger thing but still makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If your code works, then **no**, don't refactor. Why? Because we don't have much time here, on Earth.

Comment: @Shiva - I take offence to you calling it a 'comment'. It's an answer, damnit :P

Answer (score 1):

I think a better place for this would be http://refactormycode.com/

Stackoverflow is more geared towards direct Question and Answers, and less for discussions.